# Exoplayer works in simulator but doesn't reproduce on real device

Tags: java, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

When I run the app on the simulator it works perfectly and shows all the content, but when I install it on another device, Exoplayer just shows a black screen. I am using the demo that Exoplayer provides (demo-cast) for hls format.

Main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnClickListener, PlayerManager.Listener {

    private StyledPlayerView playerView;
    private PlayerManager playerManager;
    private RecyclerView mediaQueueList;
    private MediaQueueListAdapter mediaQueueListAdapter;
    private CastContext castContext;


    // Activity lifecycle methods.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Getting the cast context later than onStart can cause device discovery not to take place.
        try {
            castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            while (cause != null) {
                if (cause instanceof DynamiteModule.LoadingException) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.cast_context_error);
                    return;
                }
                cause = cause.getCause();
            }
            // Unknown error. We propagate it.
            throw e;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playerView.requestFocus();

        mediaQueueList = findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerViewCallback());
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(mediaQueueList);
        mediaQueueList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mediaQueueList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mediaQueueListAdapter = new MediaQueueListAdapter();

        findViewById(R.id.add_sample_button).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (castContext == null) {
            // There is no Cast context to work with. Do nothing.
            return;
        }
        playerManager =
                new PlayerManager(/* listener= */ this, this, playerView, /* context= */ castContext);
        mediaQueueList.setAdapter(mediaQueueListAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (castContext == null) {
            // Nothing to release.
            return;
        }
        mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, mediaQueueListAdapter.getItemCount());
        mediaQueueList.setAdapter(null);
        playerManager.release();
        playerManager = null;
    }

    // Activity input.

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event was not handled then see if the player view can handle it.
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event) || playerManager.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.add_samples)
                .setView(buildSampleListView())
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    // PlayerManager.Listener implementation.

    @Override
    public void onQueuePositionChanged(int previousIndex, int newIndex) {
        if (previousIndex != C.INDEX_UNSET) {
            mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(previousIndex);
        }
        if (newIndex != C.INDEX_UNSET) {
            mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(newIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnsupportedTrack(int trackType) {
        if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            showToast(R.string.error_unsupported_audio);
        } else if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            showToast(R.string.error_unsupported_video);
        }
    }

    // Internal methods.

    private void showToast(int messageId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), messageId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private View buildSampleListView() {
        View dialogList = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample_list, null);
        ListView sampleList = dialogList.findViewById(R.id.sample_list);
        sampleList.setAdapter(new SampleListAdapter(this));
        sampleList.setOnItemClickListener(
                (parent, view, position, id) -> {
                    playerManager.addItem(DemoUtil.SAMPLES.get(position));
                    mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(playerManager.getMediaQueueSize() - 1);
                });
        return dialogList;
    }

    // Internal classes.

    private class MediaQueueListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QueueItemViewHolder> {

        @Override
        public QueueItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TextView v =
                    (TextView)
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                    .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            return new QueueItemViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(QueueItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.item = Assertions.checkNotNull(playerManager.getItem(position));

            TextView view = holder.textView;
            view.setText(holder.item.mediaMetadata.title);
            // TODO: Solve coloring using the theme's ColorStateList.
            view.setTextColor(
                    ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(
                            view.getCurrentTextColor(),
                            position == playerManager.getCurrentItemIndex() ? 255 : 100));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return playerManager.getMediaQueueSize();
        }
    }

    private class RecyclerViewCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

        private int draggingFromPosition;
        private int draggingToPosition;

        public RecyclerViewCallback() {
            super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN, ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END);
            draggingFromPosition = C.INDEX_UNSET;
            draggingToPosition = C.INDEX_UNSET;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(
                RecyclerView list, RecyclerView.ViewHolder origin, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            int fromPosition = origin.getAdapterPosition();
            int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
            if (draggingFromPosition == C.INDEX_UNSET) {
                // A drag has started, but changes to the media queue will be reflected in clearView().
                draggingFromPosition = fromPosition;
            }
            draggingToPosition = toPosition;
            mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            QueueItemViewHolder queueItemHolder = (QueueItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
            if (playerManager.removeItem(queueItemHolder.item)) {
                mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                // Update whichever item took its place, in case it became the new selected item.
                mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
            if (draggingFromPosition != C.INDEX_UNSET) {
                QueueItemViewHolder queueItemHolder = (QueueItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
                // A drag has ended. We reflect the media queue change in the player.
                if (!playerManager.moveItem(queueItemHolder.item, draggingToPosition)) {
                    // The move failed. The entire sequence of onMove calls since the drag started needs to be
                    // invalidated.
                    mediaQueueListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            draggingFromPosition = C.INDEX_UNSET;
            draggingToPosition = C.INDEX_UNSET;
        }
    }

    private class QueueItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

        public final TextView textView;
        public MediaItem item;

        public QueueItemViewHolder(TextView textView) {
            super(textView);
            this.textView = textView;
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playerManager.selectQueueItem(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    private static final class SampleListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MediaItem> {

        public SampleListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DemoUtil.SAMPLES);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ((TextView) view).setText(Util.castNonNull(getItem(position)).mediaMetadata.title);
            return view;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checking the orientation of the screen

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

            //First Hide other objects (listview or recyclerview), better hide them using Gone.
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width=params.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height=params.MATCH_PARENT;
            playerView.setLayoutParams(params);

            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
            }
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            MainActivity.this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

            //unhide your objects here.
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width=params.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height=450;
          playerView.setLayoutParams(params);

            if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
                getSupportActionBar().show();
        }


        }
    }

}
```

HLS List Activity

```
public static final String MIME_TYPE_DASH = MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD;
public static final String MIME_TYPE_HLS = MimeTypes.APPLICATION_M3U8;
public static final String MIME_TYPE_SS = MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SS;
public static final String MIME_TYPE_VIDEO_MP4 = MimeTypes.VIDEO_MP4;

/** The list of samples available in the cast demo app. */
public static final List<MediaItem> SAMPLES;

static {
    ArrayList<MediaItem> samples = new ArrayList<>();

    // Clear content.
    samples.add(
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri("http://51.222.46.108:1935/narino/narino/playlist.m3u8")
                    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(" STV Nariño").build())
                    .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_HLS)
                    .build());
    samples.add(
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri("http://51.222.46.108:1935/8266/8266/playlist.0.m3u8")
                    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(" Teleamiga").build())
                    .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_HLS)
                    .build());
    samples.add(
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri("http://51.222.46.108:1935/8164/8164/playlist.m3u8")
                    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(" IDMJI").build())
                    .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_HLS)
                    .build());
    samples.add(
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri("http://51.222.46.108:1935/8026/8026/playlist.m3u8")
                    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(" Golden").build())
                    .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_HLS)
                    .build());
    samples.add(
            new MediaItem.Builder()
                    .setUri("http://51.222.46.108:1935/8160/8160/playlist.m3u8")
                    .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder().setTitle(" De pelicula").build())
                    .setMimeType(MIME_TYPE_HLS)
                    .build());


    // DRM content.


    SAMPLES = Collections.unmodifiableList(samples);
}

private DemoUtil() {}
```

And XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#292D36"
    >



    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView

        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450px"
        app:resize_mode="fill"
        app:hide_on_touch="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"


        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="@android:color/black"
        app:repeat_toggle_modes="all|one" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sample_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_sample_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_samples"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            android:background="#13568C"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid clear endpoints.
If it is just for test try to add this

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

in your AndroidManifest (application section) but don't use this workaround in a real app.